# Determine submitted number in which range

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Example: The shop has 3 different payment amount of promotion, if buy 10 get 1 credit and 20 for 2 credit...These promotions I set on config like this:

reward

```
 0
  10 amount
  1  reward
 1
  20 amount
  2  reward
 2
  30 amount
  3 reward
```

So, how can I loop or foreach these can determine my purchased amount?

note: I am new to programming so please guide me to my homework.

I expect the output should:

```
if amount=20
then

array[0] true
array[1] true 
array[3] wrong(require amount=30)
then get the final credit i get
```

Comment: is this in `php` language?

Comment: I need do in php. that is question i ask

Comment: I see. do you have to do it in array looping way or others can be acceptable?

Comment: yea. but i had problem how to loop these array out and determine my amount belong to which promotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, all you need is to loop through your config and find if your curr amount is less then config amount:

```
$config = [
    [
        'amount' => 10,
        'reward' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'amount' => 20,
        'reward' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'amount' => 30,
        'reward' => 3,
    ],
];
```

to loop through you can use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
when the condition is true there is no reason to loop more - so just [break](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

try yourself before opening the [demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/Sy4tHCMJII6oiZTf)